# Spring3 - WebFlow - JSF -- Can't get mapping of '/' to work properly

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

Sorry if this is a Newbie question, but I am trying to teach myself Spring MVC/WebFlow with JSF/Primefaces, and I've run into a snag setting it up...

If in web.xml, I set the MVC dispatcher to a catch all '/', then register `@RequestMapping(value = "/{catchall}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, in my controller.  The page is served, but the resources files all have the {catchall} name prepended to the start of the name e.g.

If I use //127.0.0.1:8080/testpage

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/testpage/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2" />
```

This results in every resource being NOT FOUND, and returning a 404 error?

If instead of a 'catch-all', I set the MVC dispatcher to '/a/*', the perform the same test, e.g.

//127.0.0.1:8080/a/testpage, it works fine with the resources being shown as:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/a/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2" />
```

I am trying to setup a system where the page is served dynamically from the datastore, and want the page to be - www.whatever.com/{pagename} - without any prefixed structure, or postfixed identifier (e.g. .jsp, .jsf, .xhtml, etc.)

I can post configs if required, but am sure I'm just missing something stupid!!!!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried I found that the Sun Mojarra library assumes your servlet mapping is either a prefix mapping or a servlet mapping by extension (but not the default servlet mapping "/"). Your best bet to use URLs without a servlet prefix might be to use URL rewriting techniques such as Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter or in JSF PrettyFaces is quite popular.

Comment: Thanks - So is it the Mojarra library that is writing the URLS for the libraries then?   I had assumed it was Spring doing this!  I also assumed that it was Spring that is mishandling the request, i.e. not finding the resource under /testpage, but finding it at /a - Is this also Mojarra?